# Pass parameters in websockets php

Tags: php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I seen a example on html5 websockets with php at [here](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket).

I want to pass parameters in url. So I used like shown below in index.php

```
              var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/demo/server.php?name=Jhon";  
              websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

And in server.php I used

```
              $user = $_REQUEST['name'];
```

Then I got error

```
              Undefined index:name in server.php
```

Similarly I tried with session but it too didn't worked.

How can I pass parameters to server.php on websoket connection opened.

Comment: curious error: **Undefibed**

Comment: @Dagon sorry it's undefined

Comment: you should not be attaching a parameter to the host but pushing it through the socket.

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameter with socket.send() after handshake as follow:

```
    var msg = {
    name: "jhon",
    otherparam:"value"
    };
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```